# GridView Control Colors per Row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have another jquery question/suggestion upgrade etc.

I have an asp.net GridView, which holds several fields that the user can edit. I have an onchange() on one of the textbox fields so the color changes if the value is > 5 or whatever. This works fine.

Now in document.ready I need that same css styling to apply to fields already saved. E.g., the problem I'm having is that if the user has saved data and is returning to view it, the onchange() color changes no longer display (obviously).

I have the following code as received from a different link:

```
 $('.myGridClass tr').each(function () {

            var number = $(this).children('td:eq(4)').text();
            var ugh = $(this).children('td:eq(4)').css();

            if (number == 0) {
                $(this).children('td').css('color', 'black');
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('td').css('color', 'red');
            }
        })
```

Now the `var number = $(this).children('td:eq(4)').text();` works perfectly fine, it gets the correct value from the correct column etc. But the color changes are not working correctly. It doesn't change the color value of the specified textbox.

Any suggestions on how to tweak this would be much appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert text to integer in order to match with numbers:

```
 $('.myGridClass tr').each(function () {

            var number = parseInt($(this).children('td:eq(4)').text());
            var ugh = $(this).children('td:eq(4)').css();

            if (number == 0) {
                $(this).children('td:eq(4)').css('color', 'black');
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('td:eq(4)').css('color', 'red');
            }
        })
```

Comment: This is not quite the problem I'm having, as I said, the number returns fine, the if fires correctly and the code gets executed. The trouble I'm having is that colour being set is the footer row, not the item itself (i.e. not the textbox in column 4 where the value is 0)

Comment: Sadly I've tried that too. Still does nothing. Somehow I'm referencing the textbox in whichever row is currently being executed wrong. Or alternatively it does change the colour but for some reason when it goes to the next row the colour changes are lost? I don't know.

Comment: You need to do something like this, though it is not tested: `$(this).children('td:eq(4)').children(':text').each(function(){ $(this).css('color', 'black'); });`